# Uncentered Abstract in Lyx

Tags: lyx, abstract, lyx-layouts

I am using the AEA template for Lyx. For some reason my abstract is not centering properly...it appears to be slightly shifted to left. This is what the output looks like:

[image]

This is how my Lyx looks like:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If you use the AEA .lyx template and paste in your abstract (or just write random words to get a paragraph), do you see the issue there? I just did that and I do not see it. Either it is differences in our LaTeX distributions or differences between your .lyx file and the AEA template .lyx file. Also, what is your LaTeX distribution?

Comment: did you get the issue figured out?

Comment: I am using MiKTeX. Using random words does not make a difference. My co-author also has the same problem on his computer when he tries to compile...

Comment: Thanks for the update, sorry to hear you're still seeing it.